# How do I declare an two dimension array in c++ whose first dimension is not known?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I want to declare an two dimension array, but I don't know first dimension. Second dimension is known.

How do I declare the array?

I found one syntax:

```
int (*p) [5];
```

Is it correct syntax? But I do not understand this syntax.

Comment: In c or c++ ????  Tagging `c`  and in title `c++` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dynamic memory ;)...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define KNOWN_DIMENSION 16

int main() {
    size_t unknownDimension = rand() % 32 + 1;

    int **dynamic = malloc(unknownDimension * sizeof(int*));
    if(dynamic == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < unknownDimension; i++) {
        dynamic[i] = malloc(KNOWN_DIMENSION * sizeof(int));
        if(dynamic[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // `dynamic` is usable as an `int[unknownDimension][KNOWN_DIMENSION]` here!

    for(size_t i = 0; i < unknownDimension; i++)
        free(dynamic[i]);

    free(dynamic);
    return 0;
}
```

**BTW**: `int (*p)[5]` is the same as a pointer to `int p[5]`.

Comment: No, `int (*p)[5]` **is not** the same as `int p[5]`.

Comment: @EnzoFerber: Thanks! That was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
int (*p) [5];
```

means "p is a pointer to an array of five ints".
This pointer can be a pointer to the first element of an array in the normal way.

If you have an array whose elements are five-element arrays of `int`s, you can use the normal array-to-pointer conversion:

```
int array[10][5] = {};
int (*p)[5] = array;
```

or

```
int (*p)[5] = &array[0];
```

You can of course also allocate dynamically, which I suspect you want to do:

```
int (*p)[5] = new int[10][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this requires dynamic memory.

However if standard containers can be used C++11 provides the `array` container:

```
vector<array<int, 5>> foo;
```

Which provides 4 primary benefits over dynamic memory:

1. It is easy to create and zero initialize elements of `foo`: For example to create two size 5, zeroed second dimensions you need only do: `foo.resize(2)`
2. There is never a need to `delete` allocated memory. As soon as `foo` goes out of scope it will be cleaned up. Whether by throwing an error or any natural scope exit
3. `vector` can attend to reallocation and data copying as the array dynamically grows or shrinks over the course of program execution
4. If this is a member variable using a container that properly constructs and copies itself allows you to use the default generated constructors, assignment operators, and destructor

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/hUUG4o)]